# Threadsafe way to have unique consecutive values

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have code like this:

```
static volatile int i = 0;
static void Foo() {
int myInt = i++;
// now use myInt
}
```

I need to have each value of `myInt` unique and consecutive. For example, if there will be running 5 such threads, they should have `myInt` values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` (order isn't important).

So, I want no know if this way is thread-safe or not, and what's the best way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For thread safety use [Interlocked.Increment()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx):

> Increments a specified variable and
>   stores the result, as an atomic
>   operation.

```
    int MyInt = Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
```

[...and there is no reason to mark as volatile, which is somewhat broken and might be deprecated/removed in future versions of C# ...]

Comment: @chersanya See Eric Lippert's recent blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx